# Do I need to migrate from iptables to nftables?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, nftables

I have the following iptables rules.

Forwarding packets from 1.2.3.4 and 5.6.7.8 (sources) coming to port 10000 to an external socks5 server on 10.10.10.10:1080. The server IP is 50.50.50.50

This schema is working well if the source amount is not high and at the same time the external socks5 amount is not high too. Once I have 50 sources and 30k external socks -  iptables is stuck and no packets forwarding so I suspect there is a limit in iptables performance. Can someone tell me if nftables is more powerful and if yes - how to translate my rules to nftables?

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1:40]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:40]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

-A PREROUTING -s 1.2.3.4,5.6.7.8 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.10:1080
-A POSTROUTING -d 10.10.10.10/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1080 -j SNAT --to-source 50.50.50.50

COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [15:1012]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [26:1348]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [9:932]
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough explanation of what can go wrong.

- Before the *iptables* rules:

  X (X=2 in OP's starting example) source IP addresses with 2^16 possible source ports and 1 destination address and port:

  X * 2^16 possible connections.
- After the *iptables* rules: X sources got squashed into one source

  1 * 2^16 possible connections.

X * 2^16 connections can't be made to fit into only 2^16 connections. Source port collision will start happening more and more often, and be resolved by changing the source port, but finding a free source port not clashing with an other flow will become increasingly harder: performance degradation starts increasing, dropped packets can even start happening.

Would this happen differently if *iptables* were replaced with *nftables*? No. In both cases, they are not the parts resolving the collision. This resolution is done in the same common Netfilter backend: [the `nf_nat` kernel module](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/netfilter/nf_nat_core.c?h=v5.15#n467), possibly iterating multiple times if needed and even giving up (ie: dropping the new *conntrack* entry and the packet having triggered its tentative creation).

The cause is the source NAT done when there's a single possible destination (the server): it should be avoided.

Possible workarounds:

- don't use source NAT. An adequate routing (even if this requires multi-homing or a tunnel) put in place so 10.10.10.10 doesn't have to see a single 50.50.50.50 source should be done instead. The question doesn't explain why this SNAT is required, so it's not possible to detail further.
- have multiple sources addresses to load balance with and spread the source port pressure. This can be achieved with *iptables* using the [`statistic`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#statistic) module to load balance to multiple `SNAT` targets.

Switching to *nftables* is usually an improvement, but for this case, this doesn't appear to be the solution.